# Getopt::Long - How to get script arguments that are not options

Tags: perl

*Taken from the manual page [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long):*

The code is:

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $data   = "file.dat";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose;
GetOptions ("length=i" => \$length,    # numeric
            "file=s"   => \$data,      # string
            "verbose"  => \$verbose)   # flag
or die("Error in command line arguments\n");
```

And I execute the script thus:

```
./myscript.pl --verbose filename.txt
```

How do I get hold of the argument `filename.txt`?

Comment: It'll be in `@ARGV`.

Comment: Their parser goes through `@ARGV` and removes all arguments that are set up (here `length`, `file`, `verbose`) and their values, if any (for `length` and `file` here).  Everything else that was on the command line stays in `@ARGV`.  So either parse it by hand after `GetOptions` is done or add that as a comand-line argument as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-options are left in `@ARGV`.

This means you can simply use `<>` to read from them if they're file names.

Answer (score 3):

Non option arguments are simply left in `@ARGV`.

```perl
our $argument = shift @ARGV;
```

There is a more concise way to use Getopt though.  By specifying a hash reference as the first argument, all of the options are assigned to that hash.  It's a great way to keep all of the options together in one place.  The option spec can be put into a `qw` list.

```perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use Getopt::Long;

## %options must be declared seperately because it is referenced in its own definition
our %options;
%options = (
  # set default debug level
  debug => 0,
  # set default file name
  file => "file.dat",
  # option with multi-effects, setting debug and verbose at once
  quiet => sub { @options{qw/debug verbose/} = (0, 0); },
  loud  => sub { @options{qw/debug verbose/} = (999, 1); },
);

GetOptions(\%options, qw/debug+ verbose! file=s length=o quiet loud/);

our $argument = shift @ARGV;
die "missing first argument\n" unless defined $argument;

print "Starting program $0 on $argument\n" if $options{verbose};
if ($options{debug} >= 2) {
  ## Load this module only if we need it, but you must guarantee it's there or trap the error with eval{}
  require Data::Dump;
  printf "Dumping options hash\n%s\n", Data::Dump::pp(\%options);
}
```

Comment: What's with `our`? There's no reason to use `our` instead of `my` here.

Comment: I fixed a couple typos.  But please do not litigate style.

Comment: I really don't get your beef.  Your slams and nit picking are not appreciated.  If you think that *either* `our` or `my` is "correct" you are using the wrong language.  1. `strict` in no way says that you don't want globals. 2. `our` does not create a global. 3. `our` vs `my` is style. 4. I award you 10 elitism points for using "shan't" in a sentence. 5. Please do not supply commentary on any of my posts.  Asking a direct question or pointing out an error is fine though.

Comment: Re "*1. strict in no way says that you don't want globals*, That is specifically what `use strict qw( vars );` does. /// Re "*2. our does not create a global.*", `our $x` is equivalent to `\my $x = \$CurrentPackage::x;`, which both creates and references the global `$CurrentPackage::x` /// Re "*3. `our` vs `my` is style.*", I don't care what you call breaking the fundamental tenets of CS. /// Re "*4. I award you 10 elitism points for using "shan't" ", Using street slang is elite? Okay. /// Re "*5. [...] Asking a direct question or pointing out an error is fine*", uh, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: whoa.  I don't have any beef with anyone.  (And I don't see why you say ikegami did, for an appropriate, and purely programming, question, but perhaps that's on me.) But there's code involved and I'd like to add to the discussion.  So ... you don't want `our`, for any number of reasons, unless there is a _specific reason_ for it, normally in libraries.  It's not style.  The `my` or `our` is not a question of style.  That `our` **is** a way to do global with `strict` on. (From [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our) -- "_makes a lexical alias to a package (i.e. global) variable..._")

Comment: As you introduce a good feature (hash for cmdline arguments), I'd like to pose a few questions.  (1) That `require` is going to bomb the program, _unexpectedly_, if the module isn't available. Why not handle that -- or at least warn the reader. I'm sure you know this but the natural audience for this page doesn't. (2) Invoking the program with `quiet` overrides `debug` ... or the other way round? I think a comment is needed for that, if you insist on it. Why declare `%options` separately from assignment to it?  It may help for this audience to see it done "normally."

Comment: @zdim I really appreciate those questions.  Thank you for asking them.  The two normal arguments against `our` are that it's slower and that it permits distant code to meddle with your internals.  I've never seen that speed difference over many benchmarks and it wouldn't matter for normal code anyway.  It makes sense to use `our` when a variable should be available throughout the program and `my` when it should be limited to a scope.  I'ld like to hear the use case against `our`.

Comment: Re "_...case against `our`_" -- Just what you said, it involves "_distant code_"  -- that breaks some very basic principles, right? I am certain you know why we don't want globals (given that there are good options), and in fact we want to minimize any unwarranted "coupling" (of distinct functionalities) in code.  We want distinct code segments fully encapsulated, so that they get input only via a specific interface.  Etc. I mean, you know this. The only bit here is that `our` **is indeed** a global (perhaps you didn't appreciate that?).

Comment: @zdim `strict refs` only makes you declare variables or qualify them as a sanity checking mechanism.  `our` only creates a lexical alias to a global. As if `my $foo; ALIAS($foo, $__PACKAGE__::foo);`  You can put `our` in a scope or sub to gain easy access to a global but *only* there.  `use vars()` is how you declare an actual global variable.  I get compartmentalization, I do. e.g. in `mod_perl` you *have* to use `my` at the top level.

Comment: Regardless of scoping.  Again from [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our), my emphasis: "_An `our` declaration declares an alias for a package variable that will be visible across its entire lexical scope, **even across package boundaries.**_  (See the code sample at this point in docs.) This is horror.  I don't want that. I don't want symbols floating around which I haven't even heard of, or that those used in a piece of code may be used by yet other pieces of code, arbitrarily removed.  Etc.  (And this is just one thing.)

Comment: But even beyond all that -- it's a special "thing" and _there is no need for it_. (Well, unless there is a very specific need, but in this answer there is absolutely no need for that.  More, most of the time there is no need for it. So we shouldn't be showing it just so.)

Comment: @zdim Re require. It would bomb at run time if not present.  You would only do this if of course if the module were guaranteed or `use`ing it was a waste of time or it's no big deal if it bombs. Re quiet. Whichever switch was called last would win. I was just showing how to have a switch that sets other switches.  Re options. I had to declare `%options` seperately because I referred to it in its own definition.  Other wise you get "undeclared variable".  I appreciate your points; I'll make a few edits.

Comment: @zdim Re *"An our declaration declares an alias for a package variable that will be visible across its entire lexical scope, even across package boundaries. (See the code sample at this point in docs.) This is horror. I don't want that.* But,,, that's exactly what `my` does (except for the alias). :P  The only effective difference between `my` and `our` is the alias into the symbol table (stash).  I also want to mention that I'm a big fan of the `state` declaration.

Comment: @zdim I understand there is a school of thought that calls for total encapsulation and strict access methods etc but IMO that is antithetical to spirit of Perl.  Perl is an open model free form language.  It is the very worst language for anyone concerned with conformity or correctness.  Here is what Perl's creator, Larry Wall, has to say on the subject.  [Perl, the first postmodern computer language](http://wall.org/~larry/pm.html)

Comment: Re "*The two normal arguments against our are that it's slower*", Faster than `my`? I suppose it's possible. It creates a lexically-scoped variable just like `my`, but I guess it doesn't have to allocate a body for the scalar (because it just borrows the one from the global). The global is created at compile time, so that's not really an issue. So it's *possible*, but the difference would be tiny. No, I did not mention speed.

Comment: @lordadmira It is without question that the difference between `my` and `our` is not limited to style. You are factually wrong that `our` is better than `my`, that it is the same, and that it will not lead to strange errors. If you use `my`, it will do what you assume. `our` does something else, and quite frankly I've never seen the need to use it. In fact, that would be a good academic question for Stackoverflow: "our -- when to use it".

Comment: Overall, this is a great example of how to use `Getopt::Long`. I learned from it, despite having used that module for years; decades even. I knew it could take coderefs, and I knew it could take a hashref, but I had never thought to put coderefs in the hashref. That said, `my` instead of `our` would make it an even better example. There's particular no advantage to using `our` in this specific case, and plenty of disadvantages of `our` in general.

Comment: Re "*in mod_perl you have to use my at the top level*", You actually have to use `our`, actually, or the subs won't be able to access the vars in the subsequent requests. (And that's only for Registry scripts; this isn't an issue for mod_perl handlers or modules using scripts and handlers.) That's one of the reasons to use `our`. The other is when you need to export package vars (`@ISA`, `@EXPORT_OK`, etc). Otherwise, encapsulation is being broken for nothing.

Comment: @ikegami What I'm referring to is the phenomenon of `our` declared variables retaining their previous values on the next call to that `mod_perl` script.  That bedeviled me for quite a while, once upon a time.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the original question:

*Taken from the manual page: [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#Mixing-command-line-option-with-other-arguments)*

> **Mixing command line option with other arguments**
>
> Usually programs take command line options as well as other arguments,
> for example, file names. It is good practice to always specify the
> options first, and the other arguments last. `Getopt::Long` will,
> however, allow the options and arguments to be mixed and 'filter out'
> all the options before passing the rest of the arguments to the
> program. To stop Getopt::Long from processing further arguments,
> insert a double dash -- on the command line:
>
> `--size 24 -- --all`
>
> In this example, `--all` will not be treated as an option, but passed to
> the program unharmed, in `@ARGV`.